# plot all rows of matrix in the same plot in R

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I want to create a plot.

x values are matt 's colnames : count.4, count.5, ...
y values are range of matt elements
the scatter POINTS on plot are corresponding matt[i,j] elemnts, such that points for each row  have the same color.

```
for (rr in 2:8) {
  rownames(matt)[rr-1] <- paste('class', rr, sep='.')
  for(cc in 4:20) {
    matt[rr-1, cc-3] <- rr * cc
    colnames(matt)[cc-3] <- paste('count', cc, sep='.')
  }
}
```

I am really stuck at how to get such plot. Any help or hint is very appreciated. I found

```
matplot (c(4:20), cbind(matt[1,]:mat[7,]), pch = 19, ylim = range(c(matt[1,]:mat[7,]))
```

I see  `cbind(matt[1,]:matt[7,])`  is not of correct format. but I do not know how to write this such than for a matrix with many more rows I do not have to write all matt[j,] 
how can I get to this?

Edit. this is the plot I get when I use `cbind(matt[1,],matt[2,],...,matt[7,])`

Other than the efficient way coding this, I do not know why there are two sets of black points. can I label colors to corresponding "class" so that the plot gets easier to be read.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally series are stored in columns, not in rows, but if they are in rows just use transpose. There are other color palettes available at `?rainbow` and a long vector of colors available via `colors()` if you don't like the colors we used here. (We used the input in the Note at the end.)

```
col <- rainbow(length(rr))
matplot(cc, t(mat), pch = 19, col = col, type = "o")
legend("topleft", legend = rownames(mat), pch = 19, col = col, lty = 1)
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

```
rr <- 2:8
cc <- 4:20
mat <- outer(rr, cc)
dimnames(mat) <- list(paste0("class.", rr), paste0("count.", cc))
```